# ADO.NET SqlCommand not returning correct value for SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, sqlcommand, scope-identity

I have a simple table :

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [NVARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
    [DATA] [NVARCHAR](max) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I have a stored procedure that inserts a row into this table and returns the value of the `PK IDENTITY` column via `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [InsertMyTable] 
    @NAME NVARCHAR(100),
    @DATA NVARCHAR(MAX)  
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([NAME], [DATA])
    VALUES (@NAME, @DATA)  

    RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

I've tested this stored procedure via SSMS and other tools and it behaves as expected.

Each time the following script is run, the returned value increments by 1 :

```
DELETE FROM [MyTable]
GO

DECLARE @return INT

EXEC @return = [InsertMyTable] @NAME='MyName', @DATA='Data'

SELECT @return
GO
```

- First run returns 1
- Second run returns 2
- etc.

However when I perform analogous actions in C# code using `System.Data.SqlClient` the stored procedure return value is always 1. It doesn't seem to reflect that the identity is incremented each time the row is deleted and re-inserted.

```
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection({connection-string}))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "delete from [MyTable] where [NAME]='MyName'";

        connection.Open();

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection({connection-string}))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "InsertMyTable";

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter($"@NAME", "MyName"));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter($"@DATA", "data"));

        connection.Open();

        var returnValue = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

- First run `returnValue = 1`
- Second run `returnValue = 1`
- etc.

Comment: your stored procedure returns the identity value as a result set, you will need a data reader in c# to read it. Use `ExecuteReader`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stored procedure returns the ID as the stored procedure return value, which should only be used for success or failure, never for data.

[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8)() returns the total of all the rowcount messages for the executed batch.

You should use an output parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [InsertMyTable] 
  @NAME NVARCHAR(100)
, @DATA NVARCHAR(MAX) 
, @ID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [MyTable]
           ([NAME]
           ,[DATA])
     VALUES
           ( @NAME
           , @DATA)  
set @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

or using a resultset, and get the value with SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar(), or SqlCommand.ExecuteReader().

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [InsertMyTable] 
  @NAME NVARCHAR(100)
, @DATA NVARCHAR(MAX)  
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [MyTable]
           ([NAME]
           ,[DATA])
     VALUES
           ( @NAME
           , @DATA)  
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() ID
END
```

You can make what you have work by binding an extra SqlParameter, but it's bad practice.